# Add a new Date column based off an existing Date column in rust polars

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I am trying to add a new column in my polars DataFrame: `'for_date'`

There is already a column named `'made_on'`, and I want `'for_date'` to be 1 day greater than `'made_on'`. So if `'made_on'` is `2022-12-25` then `for_date` should be `2022-12-26` etc.

My df looks like this:

```
┌────────────┐
│ made_on    │
│ ---        │
│ date       │
╞════════════╡
│ 2021-06-04 │
│ 2021-12-31 │
│ 2021-12-31 │
│ 2021-12-30 │
│ ...        │
│ 2022-08-06 │
│ 2022-08-06 │
│ 2022-08-06 │
│ 2022-08-06 │
└────────────┘
```

I know I can use `with_column()` on the df to transform a column but can't seem to get the types working and as a Rust newbie it's driving me a bit mad! In pseudo code I am looking for:

```rust
let df = df.with_column((col("made_on").map(/* add one day */).alias("for_date"))
```

Comment: What data type is that date column?

Comment: Running `dtypes()` on the df it says it is `Date`. In [the docs on time series](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/timeseries/parsing_dates_times.html) it says `YYYY-MM-DD` is a date so this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ensure you have the `dtype-duration` and `temporal` features enabled for the `polars` crate (these features may be on by default in some setups or versions):

```
polars = { version = "0.27.2", features = ["dtype-duration", "lazy", "temporal"] }
```

Then you can simply add a Chrono `Duration` to the date/time column you have:

```
use polars::{prelude::*, export::chrono};

fn main() -> PolarsResult<()> {
    let df = CsvReader::from_path("example.csv")?
        .infer_schema(None)
        .has_header(true)
        .with_parse_dates(true)
        .finish()?
        .lazy()
        .with_column(
            (col("made_on") + chrono::Duration::days(1).lit()).alias("for_date")
        );

    println!("{:?}", df.collect());

    Ok(())
}
```

This is not very well documented through examples, but the corresponding RustDocs for [the literal values of Chrono Duration](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/prelude/enum.LiteralValue.html#variant.Duration) shed some light.

Comment: Genius thank you! And thank you for the links to the docs!